# Amazon EC2 Linux Distro init.d script launching daemon with priority

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, daemon

I'm new to linux, and I have an script in etc/init.d which launches a daemon everytime my AWS EC2 linux server starts.  So far everything is peachy except that the daemon I have needs to launch at a slightly lower priority.  I've searched everywhere for an answer on this but to no avail.  Here's a snippet:

```
OPTIONS=" -p 49494"
prog=/home/myUser/myApp/bin/app
progName=myApp
lockfile=/var/-*lock/subsys/$progName

start() {
    [ "$EUID" != "0" ] && exit 4
    [ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 1
    [ -x $prog ] || exit 5

    # Start daemon.
    echo -n $"Starting $progName: "
    daemon --user myUser --pidfile /var/run/myApp.pid $prog $OPTIONS &
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $RETVAL
}
```

The issue is that I can't seam to launch the daemon with a priority of 5.  If I put

```
daemon -5 --user myUser  etc...
```

Then the daemon lauches without any issues with a -5 priority.  However if I put a positive number in place

```
daemon 5 --user myUser etc...
```

then the daemon doesn't launch.  I also get no notifications in any of the logs about what is going on.

Any ideas why -5 works but 5 doesn't?

p.s. I didn't write the original file, so I'd like to alter it as little as possible since its currently working fine.

Answer (score 0):

it should work if you add the appropriate flag in this case N as follows:

```
daemon -N 5 --user myUser  etc...
```

Comment: Same result as before.  The daemon still doesn't run at all even with the -N flag.  I tried different flags as well before, but with the same result.